Сдвинуть заполненные ячейки
Помогите с решением проблемы. Есть заполненные ячейки A1:A3, есть также заполненные ячейки B1:B3. Я добавляю значение в ячейку A4, и мне нужно, чтобы имеющиеся данные в диапазоне B1:B3, смещались вниз, то есть ячейка B1 стала пустой, а значения, которые были в ячейках B1:B3, переместились в ячейки B2:B4
ну собственно выравнивание второго столбца должно всегда происходить по нижнему заполненному значению первого столбца
До

После

стоит отметить, что ячейки в первом столбце заполнены функцией IMPORTAGE
тригер на изменение добавил и дал ему все разрешения
я совершенно не рабираюсь в javascript.
Я попробовал следующий код, но он не работает:
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e && e.source) {
    if (e.source.getSheetName() !== 'Calculation') return;
  }
  if (e) {
    if (e.range && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 1 && e.value != '') {
      var row = e.range.rowStart + 2;
      var column = e.range.columnStart + 1;
      var nextRow = row + 1;
      var nextColumn = column;
      var range = e.range.offset(nextRow, 0);
      if (SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Calculation').getRange(range).isBlank()) {
        // Если диапазон пуст, активируем его
        SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Calculation').getRange(range).activate();
      } else {
        // Если диапазон не пуст, добавляем сообщение об ошибке
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Ошибка: диапазон не пуст");
      }
    } else if (e.range && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart >= 2 && e.range.rowStart <= 3) {
      var row = e.range.rowStart + 1;
      var column = e.range.columnStart + 1;
      var nextRow = row + 1;
      var nextColumn = column;
      var range = e.range.offset(nextRow, 0);
      if (SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Calculation').getRange(range).isBlank()) {
        // Если диапазон пуст, активируем его
        SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Calculation').getRange(range).activate();
      } else {
        // Если диапазон не пуст, добавляем сообщение об ошибке
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Ошибка: диапазон не пуст");
      }
    }
  }
}

Что ж, я написал свой собственный код, который работает почти хорошо. но, к сожалению, функция onEdit не учитывает, что диапазон изменяется функцией IMPORTAGE. Мне пришлось добавить флажок, при изменении которого функция начинает работать. но я хотел бы автоматически отслеживать изменения, принимая во внимание, что диапазон изменяется с помощью функции ИМПОРТА.
  function onEdit(e) {
 if (e && e.source) {
 if (e.source.getSheetName() !== 'Calculation') return;
 }
 if (e) {
 if (e.range && e.range.columnStart == 37 && e.range.rowStart >= 1 && e.range.rowEnd <= 1) {
 const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
 const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 const valuesA = sheet.getRange('AK4:AK102').getValues();
 const valuesB = sheet.getRange('AL4:AL102').getValues();
 // Здесь обрабатываем filteredValues
 // Подсчёт значений во всём диапазоне
 const allValuesA = valuesA.flat(); // Сглаживаем массив значений
 const stringValuesA = allValuesA.filter(String); // Удаляем нестроковые значения
 const countA = stringValuesA.length; // Считаем количество оставшихся значений
 const allValuesB = valuesB.flat(); // Сглаживаем массив значений
 const stringValuesB = allValuesB.filter(String); // Удаляем нестроковые значения
 const countB = stringValuesB.length; // Считаем количество оставшихся значений
 // Находим индекс последней строки с данными в диапазоне AK4:A103
 const lastRowWithDataIndexA = valuesA.findLastIndex(row => row.join('').trim() !== '')+4;
 // Находим индекс последней строки с данными в диапазоне AL4:AL103
 const lastRowWithDataIndexB = valuesB.findLastIndex(row => row.join('').trim() !== '')+4;
 const firstRowWithDataIndexB = valuesB.findIndex(row => row.join('').trim() !== '')+4;
 const firstDataB = lastRowWithDataIndexB-countB+1
 const targetFirstDataPosB = lastRowWithDataIndexA-countB+1
 const targetRange = sheet.getRange(targetFirstDataPosB, 38, 10, 1); // Целевой диапазон смещен на rowCount строк вниз
 sheet.getRange(firstDataB, 38, valuesB.length, 1).copyTo(targetRange, {contentsOnly: true}); // Копирование содержимого столбца B в целевой диапазон
 const delData = targetFirstDataPosB-4
 if (targetFirstDataPosB >= 4) {
 sheet.getRange(4, 38, delData, 1).clear({contentsOnly: true});
 }

 }
 }
}

не могли бы вы подсказать мне, как лучше всего это реализовать?

нужен скрипт который по сути проверяет сколько заполненных ячеек в первом столбце и находит последнюю заполненную ячейку, и просто смещает значения из второго столбца до этой же строки. повторюсь что первый столбец заполняется функцией IMPORTAGE. добавление значений всегда происходит с верхних ячеек.

Триггер на изменение в данном случае работать не будет. Включите триггер по времени каждую минуту.

Задача странная, но она дает повод продемонстрировать, как можно двигать диапазоны в Таблицах с помощью Apps Script

Полный листинг
function moveDataDown_() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Сдвигать данные вниз');
  const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  const lastIndexFormula = values.findLastIndex((row) => row[0] !== '');
  const lastIndexData = values.findLastIndex((row) => row[1] !== '');

  if (lastIndexData >= lastIndexFormula) {
    return;
  }

  const range = sheet.getRange(2, 2, lastIndexData, 1);
  range.moveTo(range.offset(lastIndexFormula - lastIndexData, 0));
}

/* exported triggerActionMoveDown */
function triggerActionMoveDown() {
  moveDataDown_();
}

Функцию triggerActionMoveDown нужно просто передать в триггер по времени, который срабатывает каждую минуту. Ну, и, навсякий случай, добавить в меню.

Пример в Таблице https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qdh4mQLiEL19_xDherl28CN75eUhQgUNbZLWvsHxD24/edit?gid=79424921#gid=79424921&range=A1

Добрый день, отредактировал вопрос. триггер на каждую минуту это очень долго, начал читать про функцию onChange либо onSelectionChange но пока никак не могу заставить ее работать.

Ваш код очень хорош. Я, к сожалению, абсолютный ноль в JavaScript пользовался помощью GPT, из-за этого код очень громоздкий с кучей лишних переменных которые я выводил иной раз просто чтоб понять что в них содержится.

Мне кажется, вм нужно попробовать. Не думаю, что это будет сильный дискомфорт.
